# Checking dataframe cells to see if they contain a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a fairly simple code such as

```
import pandas
df_import=pandas.read_excel("dataframe.xlsx")
df_import['Company'].str.contains('value',na=False,case=False)
```

So this obviously imports pandas, creates a dataframe from an excel documentment and then searches the column titled Company for some value, and returns an index saying if the value of that cell contains that value (True or False)

However, I want to test 3 cases. Case A, no results were found (all False), case 2, only 1 case was found (only 1 True) and case 3, more that 1 result was found (# of True > 1).

My though is that I could set up a for loop, iterating through the column, and if a value of a cell is True, I add 1 to a variable (lets call it count). Then at the end, I have an if/elif/elif statement based on the value of count, whether it is 0,1,or >1.

Now, maybe there is a better way to check this but if not, I figured the for loop would look something like

```
for i in range (len(df_improt.index))
    if df_import.iloc[i,0].str.contains('value',na=False,case=False)
        count += 1
```

First of all, I'm not sure if I should use .iloc or .iat but both give me the error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

and I wasn't able to find a correction for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is not going to work because `iloc[i, 0]` returns a scalar value, and of course, those don't have `str` accessor methods associated with them.

---

A quick and easy fix would be to just call `sum` on the series level `str.contains` call.

```
count = df_import['Company'].str.contains('value', na=False, case=False).sum()
```

Now, `count` contains the number of matches in that column.

Comment: That does, in fact, answer the underlying question. Just curious though, if I wanted to use the for loop how would I properly does that. Or is there a better way to tell if a specific cell contains a searched value. If it's too complicated to answer in a comment then that's fine

Comment: @jon Oh sorry, forgot to address that. Added it now, but yeah. Always try to avoid iteration as much as you can.